# adding images to a java applet?

Tags: java, eclipse, image

When I tried to to create an image I was using this line but got no images, just blank lines.

```
g.drawImage(getImage(getDocumentBase(), "Piece_1.png"),coorx, 
coory, SIZE_Y / 8, SIZE_Y / 8, this);
```

How do you display an image and where do you put it in an eclipse project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse IDE executes the programs from the `src` directory. These steps solved me this problem.

1. Create a new package called `resources`. You can name it whatever you want.
2. Add your image files into that package.
3. Now first load your image before drawing it.

   ```
   public Image getImage(String name){
       URL imgUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/"+name);
       ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imgUrl);
       return icon.getImage();
   }
   ```

### An Example

The constructor you can have.

```
Image piece1;

public Checkers(){
    piece1 = getImage("Piece_1.png");
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    if (piece1!=null){
        g.drawImage(piece1, xcoord, ycoord, null);
    }
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I'm getting a null pointer on the last line: `return new ImageIcon(imgUrl).getImage();`

Comment: It may be because the image files must be in the `recources` package

Comment: they are in the resource `resources` package